# How to export request Json string using DeveloperTools/Network of FF or Chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

We want to rewrite a large web project. To make the work more safe we want to cover it by numerous API tests that will be extracted from peeking at the real web calls. (And let us be honest, from the code analysis, too).

Thus I am trying to extract the Json strings sent by different requests. The problem is that the tool provided by the browser (it is practically the same for both FF and Chrome) gives me the Json in a structured form. And I need to use it as strings.

To rewrite all large and deeply structured strings from more than a hundred of requests manually is a horror. How can I copypaste the string representation of request parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in Chrome - near the "request payload" header there is a switch: `view source` <-> `view parsed`. The first variant shows the Json string. BTW, IE has buttons for that and FF... has nothing?

Comment: Params tab shows JSON if valid JSON, Request payload otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about structured and source representations. I need the last one.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox: Right click > Copy > Copy POST Data.

You can also "Copy All As HAR" to get the raw body (of every request and response in the list), and "Edit and Resend" will show you the raw body in the UI.

Comment: And where should I right click for it? For you can be sure I tried this in many places.